# Ember data route with handler and api call in different location

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Im new to Ember development and trying to build an Ember app using Ember data which connects to an API.

My API in the location **http://localhost:3000/api/panelists** returns

```
{  
   "panelists":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "secret":"",
         "isDisabled":"false",
         "disabledAt":"null",
         "isLocked":"false",
         "isSecretExpired":"false",
         "invalidAuthCount":"0",
         "givenName":"Sma",
         "middleName":"na",
         "surname":"ran",
         "avatarMimeType":"JPEG",
         "avatarFilePath":"/home/sample.jpeg",
         "createdAt":"2015-11-27T12:17:05.000Z",
         "isDeactivated":"false"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now in my Ember App, the model handler for this case is in the following location, **App_Root/app/panelists/model.js**

The specific required route is in the following path, **App_Root/app/directory/route.js**

Now, how do I hit the API **http://localhost:3000/api/panelists** with model **App_Root/app/panelists/model.js** and with the route **App_Root/app/directory/route.js?**

Current Implementation:
**route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('panelists');
  },
});
```

Getting the following error in browser:

```
WARNING: Encountered "panelists" in payload, but no model was found for model name "panelist" (resolved model name using golf-digest-panelists@serializer:-rest:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("panelists"))

Error while processing route: directory Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push' Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push'
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:24738:21)
    at assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14639:13)
    at Object.assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:22040:34)
    at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend._pushInternalModel (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:72829:15)
    at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.push (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:72815:34)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67700:17
    at Object.Backburner.run (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9710:25)
    at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend._adapterRun (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73042:33)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67697:15
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This path `App_Root/app/panelists/model.js` is wrong for your model. It should be `App_Root/app/panelist/model.js` without plural. Also, if you aren't using a `pod` structure, the common path for models is `App_Root/app/model/panelist.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the plural by changing

```
return this.store.findAll('panelists');
```

to

```
return this.store.findAll('panelist');
```